# How to display MySQL value with zerofill

Tags: javascript, mysql

Im using MySQL, ajax and c# for my website, I have a page with an input which display this query:

```
Select MAX(Id) from table
```

Then in my ajax call in the success function I have this:

```
var id = data.d + 1;
```

At the moment in my empty table I have Id with identity and autoincrement = 1, so var id = 0 + 1; so my input value its 1 and then changes when a row its inserted.

Problem:

I want to start identity in 00001, I alter table and add zerofill, so now my first row its 000001, but when I want to display the next id in my input shows 0, 1, 2 or whatever but without 0's.

Question:

How can I display the value with 0's?

Comment: As you already noticed, zerofill only has an effect when displaying the data. A client (like workbench or mysql command line tool) has to do that itself. In your case, your app is the client and you have to display it where you display your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lpad`  (left pad) to show a numeric value as zero-fill text:

```
Select lpad(MAX(Id),5,'0') from table;
```

**Edit:** A zero-filled value in Javascript will be converted to numeric and the result will be a regular numeric (non zero-fill)

Javascript:

```
var id = ("00000" + (parseInt(data.d) + 1));
var zerofillid = id.substring(id.length -5); // =00002
```

You can use `zerofillid` to display in your end.

Comment: Now my query is that, ajax function the same, but still showing 1, 2, 3, without 0's.

Comment: so, That is no a MySQL problem... you must convert you datatype before show in c#

Comment: Ajax returning 0, and its supposed to be 000001.

Comment: That means that your table is empty... and need to handle that situation

Comment: Table its not empty, thats the reason because its supposed to get 000001 and the in ajax do data.d + 1 to get 000002

Comment: Changed my answer to meet your specs... because it needs javascript code instead of mysql sql.

Comment: This help me to display the value, but for execute the data.d + 1 I have to change all my method, but finally works! Thanks.

Comment: Off topic last question, you know how to do this but with jQueryDataTables, I have this $('#Tabla').dataTable({
                "aaData": JSON.parse(data.d),
                "aoColumns": [{
                    "mDataProp": "Id"
                },

But again Id = 1, 2, 3 and must be 000001, etc. I try to do the same and concatenate "mDataProp": ' " ' + zerofillid + ' " ' but doesnt work.

Comment: Must create a new question on stackoverflow and bring detailed explanation.... don't forget to add javascript and jquery tags.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this on your databse label is not a good idea. Just change the id field that you get from ajax in this appropriate format.

```js
function (data) { 
//Success Event
var id = data.d + 1;
id = pad (id, 6); // now id will be in the format you wanted.
 $('#ID').val(id); 
} 

function pad (str, max) {
  str = str.toString();
  return str.length < max ? pad("0" + str, max) : str;
}
/*********Like for example, the function will work as****//
pad("1", 6);    // => "000001" ....when id = 1
pad("12", 6);  // => "000012"  ....when id = 12
pad("123", 6); // => "000123"  ....when id = 123
pad("1234", 6); // => "001234"   ....when id = 1234
pad("12345", 6); // => "012345"  ....when id = 12345
pad("123456", 6); // => "123456"  ....when id = 123456
```

Comment: How can i add that to my function  success: function (data) { //Success Event
            id = data.d + 1;
            $('#ID').val(id);
        }

Comment: This displays the correct format, but ajax is returning 0 and thats wrong ajax must return 000001 and your function have to show 000002 but display 000001.

Comment: What do you mean? The way i have answered, you should have your database id is normal 1, 2, 3 and so on....Now, if AJAX returns 0 then 0 plus 1 = 1 is 1 and that function will display 000001. Isn't this what you want???

Comment: In my table I have a row with id 000001, you solve the problem of display but in different way that I expected, your function do this 0 + 1 and add the 0's, my problem its do 000001(current id) + 1 to finally show 000002 in my input.

Comment: That is what I meant in my first line, it is difficult to work with the row id when it is 000001 because, when adding, this will go back to just 1 (without the zeroes). So just make your row id as 1, 2, 3...return it with ajax, add 1 to this, then pass it to the pad function to get the leading zeroes. the assign it as $(#ID).val(id); However, even now, you should be getting things correct with the row id as 000001. I don't know what the error is. Please provide more code and screen shots

Comment: Problem solved, thanks for your help but the answer above help me more, but honestly thank you very much for your time, this was a problem hard to explain and hard to understand but thanks again bro!